# Design Pattern for a Question / Answer auditing software

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I would like to build some sort of survey/ auditing software.
I am brainstorming how to build my classes and if there is a design pattern that could support me. Because ther must be something that makes life eaysier...

My application should have questions which contains a title and a description.
And then I have multiple types of answers.

So... one type could be a yes/no answer
Another type could be a value between 1 and 10.
Another type could free text answer
Another type could be a three given text choices where you can select one (The dinner was excellent, good, nod bad)

So on the survey planning site I would write down my questions and assign answer types.

And on executing the survey I want to tread it like a collection of questions with an answer...

Basically the question is how to unify all the different answer types and how to store them in the database?

I looked at composite and strategy pattern but I am not sure...
and I know there is not perfect solution and it always depends...

But it would be great if someone can share best practice on how they dealed with similar topics...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to be asking here is what are the different entity mapping strategies that are available to you in the database? In short you can have:

1. a table per entity
2. a single table for all entities with a discriminator value to identify each one (values could be just a tokenized string for example) - essentially a big Map
3. a table per entity with 1:1 join for optional properties

Your ORM solution then reads the data back from the database and turns it into the appropriate type of object (the entity) populating the fields as it goes.

In terms of the middle tier, you will need the following classes:

**AbstractQuestion**

An abstract base class for questions. Containing title, description and abstract ask() and answer() methods. There will be a variety of subclasses for AbstractQuestion that provide different display messages depending on the type of question. For example, MultiChoiceQuestion will implement the ask() method in such a way that the title and description get displayed (you could pull this up into the AbstractQuestion ask() method) along with all the choices available (which is specific to each subclass). This could be generalised so that ask() takes a Map as a parameter which can be populated with anything you like. Or you could use varargs - whatever.

**Answer**

Just a simple class containing a Map with known keys representing the different aspects of the answer with a reference to the owning AbstractQuestion.

**Questionaire**

A collection of AbstractQuestions arranged in a list. For each AbstractQuestion call the ask() method, wait for user input, then call the answer() method with the provided data.

No need for complex design patterns, unless you count abstract base classes as a pattern. The above is not complete, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I looked at TPT and TPH and I think this will be the decision for the datastore. But I am more thinking about the layer in the middle... beyond the ORM...

Comment: @serverinfo Edited to better target the question